# log messages from non-default module not showing up in google app engine console

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, python-module

My app has two modules, one of them configured to run on a manual scaling instance.  In the developer console I am able to see the log messages printed by the default module, but not the ones printed by the other module.  Is there some setting that I need to enable to see these logs?

Also, if someone has a sample project in python that uses multiple modules (one of them configured to run on manual scaling instance), I would appreciate it if you could point me to it,

Answer (score 4):

The old log viewer is slated for deprecation on March '22 (this month).
The new one is available in OPERATIONS -> Logging -> Logs Explorer from the GCP console menu (or at https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query). The Logging menu can be pinned for easy access.

You may need to click on RESOURCE TYPE -> GAE Application to see details:
[image]

In the detailed view you can select the module(s) you desire as well as a pile of other filtering options:
[image]

-- Original answer below --

Logs for each modules (including default) are visible in separate views. You can select the module whose logs to display from the 2nd drop-down menu at the top of the logs table:

[image]

Comment: Initially, that dropbox only had Default listed.  Now the non-default module is shown.  But when I select there are no logs that indicate on why the module did not start as expected.  if the module started, then the logs I expect to be printed periodically (what I see when deploy on localhost) are not there.