# Google app engine Server Error. Where is the log?

Tags: google-app-engine

After deploying my application on google app engine I get this error:

```
Error: Server Error
```

`The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.`

Brower tab says "**500 Server Error**".

The problem is there any way to actually know where the error occurred? Or why am I seeing this error?

Comment: are you using cloud logging ?

Comment: Use this for logs in the google cloud shell
> gcloud app logs tail -s default

Answer (score 5):

You can see the app's logs in the [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).

If your app has multiple modules you should check the logs for each module, see [log messages from non-default module not showing up in google app engine console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070093/log-messages-from-non-default-module-not-showing-up-in-google-app-engine-console).

Comment: Thank you!.. found some problems in log.

Comment: @dan cornilescu did the log move by chance? I see logs but no errors when I know there are clearly errors happening. Thanks!

Comment: @Trip: things changed since, indeed, I just updated the linked answer.